# VB6: Different Proxy for every WebBrowser Control?

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control, http-proxy

So far, i have never found any documentation to use different proxies for each and every `webbowser` control. Is there any possible hack/tweak to use different proxy for different `webbrowser` control?

eg.

```
webbroswer1 proxy = xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx1 
webbroswer2 proxy = xx.YY.xx.xx:xxx2 
webbroswer3 proxy = xx.ZZ.xx.xx:xxx3
```

Comment: Potentially dubious use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have that much control over the web browser control. You can set the proxy for a WinInet session when making requests, but that is not exposed via the web browser control.

Comment: is there any other controls like webbrowser from firefox, opera, google chrose ?

Comment: @NokImchen There are but I've never used them, and you'll most likely have the same limitation.

Comment: @NokImchen It's nothing to do with the language. The controls just didn't envisage anyone needing to do that and so haven't spent the time to allow you to do it. Maybe if you explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish (not just what you're trying to do) there may be a better way.

Comment: i want to have full control of the raw packet data sent/received in live time and also the proxy setting

Comment: @NokImchen With aim to do what as the end result? I know what you're trying to do, but it doesn't make sense without knowing what the end result is.

Comment: i want to make a developmental browser where we can tweak anything, run javascript (like grease monkey), enable/disable certain types of pics frm certain servers/sizes/locations/folders, etc, i wanna have the control to edit the raw packet data so that we can have better control in web development

Comment: @NokImchen If you want that much control, then you will most likely have to write your own HTTP client (that will allow custom proxies, user agents, etc) and renderer and HTML engine (to handle custom scripting) or build it on top of webkit. This is NOT a simple task and definitely NOT for VB6. (Just think how long Chrome, Firefox and IE have taken to write)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27707/discussion-between-deanna-and-nok-imchen)